# Angular imports types from monorepo package as undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, monorepo

In my yarn-based monorepo project, I have 3 packages:

- `client`: Angular v15, which uses `shared` package
- `server`: NodeJS + TypeScript v5, which uses `shared` package
- `shared`: some common types, Typescript v5

Projects `client` and `server` both use `@my-project/shared` as dependency and use types exported by the package.

Both projects compile fine. However, while the server runs perfectly well, the client throws run-time errors, because somehow all those types come up as `undefined` in Angular client.

I can't figure out why that's happening. Any idea anyone?

- server's `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

- client's `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "ES2022",
    "useDefineForClassFields": false,
    "lib": [
      "ES2022",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```